# Estimating mixing matrix by k-means

Tags: matlab, k-means, mixing

I want to implement this algorithm for estimating instantaneous under-determined mixing matrix by using k-means. first we consider noise-free model, the under-determined BSS can be described as: `X=AS` where A is m by n matrix, and X is n by T matrix and S is n by T matrix. m is number of observation and S is matrix of sources and A is mixing matrix.

We generate two mixture signals by mixing together three audio sources include a guitar signal, a piano signal and drum signal.

A=[0.6118 0.9648 0.2360;0.7910 0.2629 0.9718];

the algorithm that is mentioned in this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.338.3834&rep=rep1&type=pdf) summarize this algorithm as bellow:

- Step 1. Compute the sparse coefficients of the two mixture vectors by the STFT, and obtain X(w,t)(is the stft of X) , i.e. the time frequency representation of X.
- Step 2. Normalize the vectors in X(W,t)  to move all points to a unit semi-circle for the application of the K-means algorithm.
- Step 3. Choose the starting points for the K-means algorithm, and divide X(w,t)  to three parts (equals to the number of sources) and compute the mean values of each part as the initial centers.
- Step 4. Run a K-means clustering algorithm to update iteratively the three centers until convergence, and compute the column vectors of the estimated mixing matrix A^ as the final cluster centers.

```
%% load Data

Nsamp=1024*16;           
N=3;                   %number of sources
M=2;                   %number of sensors
S=zeros(3,Nsamp);

[S(1,:),fs1]=wavread('guitar',Nsamp); % returns only the first N samples from each channel in the file.
[S(2,:),fs2]=wavread('piano',Nsamp);  % returns only the first N samples from each channel in the file.
[S(3,:),fs3]=wavread('drum',Nsamp);   % returns only the first N samples from each channel in the file.

%% Mixing Matrix
 fs=44100;

 A=[0.6118 0.9648 0.2360;0.7910 0.2629 0.9718];

for i=1:Nsamp

      X(:,i)=A*S(:,i);

end

%% STFT X
figure(3);


X1=spectrogram(X(1,:));

X2=spectrogram(X(2,:));

%normolize
X1n=X1(:)/norm(X1(:));
X2n=X2(:)/norm(X2(:));

x=[abs(X1n(:)),abs(X2n(:))];
[I C]=kmeans(x,3);
```

and my answer after implementation for center of cluster is:

```
>> C'

ans =

0.1337    0.0534    0.0008
0.1483    0.0363    0.0007
```

I don't know whats wrong with my code, and how could I estimate mixing matrix based stft by using k-means algorithm, the answer should have been much better than this.but the answer for this algorithm should be A^=C=[0.6165 0.3100 0.9247; 0.7841 0.9447 0.3547 ] as it mentioned in this paper[1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.338.3834&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

**my question is that:
1- is my implementation and my code is right for this algorithm?
2- if it is right! So why dose answer i mean mixing matrix estimation is far from the mixing matrix?**

Comment: And your question is ... ? There is way too many information in your post, except that you don't define whay's wrong with your output ...

Comment: I expect my estimation matrix(C) would be near to A! but at the end you could  understand the column of matrix is way far from the columns in A?

Comment: and also my question is that am I writing these code right? or Am i missing some part?at the end how could i estimate mixing matrix by k-means?